# Походження фразеологізму "Як кіт наплакав"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Цікавить як виник фразеологізм "Як кіт наплакав", що означає "дуже мало". Чому саме кіт, а не, наприклад, собака?

Пошуки в Інтернеті привели мене до сайту "[Як правильно зробити](http://faqukr.ru/osvita/31081-znachennja-frazeologizmu-z-kit-naplakav-istorija.html#i-2)", що дає таку версію:

> Фразеологізм «як кіт наплакав» безпосередньо пов'язаний з дзьобом
>   голуба. Цих птахів як зазвичай кличуть? «Гулі-гулі-гулі» - в
>   наслідування їх «розмови». І самих цих пернатих стали ласкаво так само
>   називати. А дзьоб - ніс голуба, гульки - в порівнянні з її тілом дуже
>   навіть крейда. Ось таке лексико-генетичне походження: «кіт наплакав» -
>   отже, щось надзвичайно маленьке, ну просто з голубиний дзьобик.

Однак, очевидно, що це недолугий переклад, а тому довіряти такій інформації не можна.

Чи є якесь офіційне або принаймі логічне пояснення походження цього фразеологізму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сайт "[Добрі поради](http://poradu.pp.ua/nauka/31927-yake-znachennya-frazeologzmu-kt-naplakav.html)" (неофіційне джерело української мови) подає дві версії походження виразу "Як кіт наплакав"

> **Перша версія виникнення**. Вона говорить, що його придумали або зоологи,
>   або любителі домашніх вихованців. Подейкують, що коли вчені вивчали
>   кішок і їх поведінку, вони помітили, що ці елегантні тварини ніколи не
>   плачуть, на відміну від інших представників свого класу. Звідси й
>   пішов вислів, що означає або дуже мала кількість чого-небудь, або його
>   повна відсутність - фразеологізм "кіт наплакав". Значення, походження
>   і вживання фрази взаємопов'язані в першій версії виникнення, тому
>   прийнято вважати це офіційним варіантом.
>
> **Друга версія виникнення.** Ця варіація історії появи фразеологізму не
>   вселяє людям довіри, у неї практично ніхто не вірить, бо звучить вона
>   неправдоподібно, буквально "притягнута за вуха". Однак версія існує і
>   має право на життя. Люди стверджують, що коли-то фразеологізм "кіт
>   наплакав" походить від арабського виразу, що перекладається як
>   "перестати отримувати достатню кількість грошей". Мабуть, араби, у
>   яких раптово перекрився потік матеріальних благ, побачили схожість
>   себе з тими, хто плаче тваринами. Звідси й походить вислів "кіт
>   наплакав". Правда, за цією версією значення фразеологізму трохи
>   відрізняється від традиційного. "Кіт наплакав" означає лише маленька
>   кількість грошей. Але так як фразеологізм завжди вживали не тільки по
>   відношенню до грошей, можна сказати, що, швидше за все, ця версія
>   вигадана.

Ще на цьому [форумі](http://posekretu.com.ua/181131-zvidki-vzyavsya-viraz-kit-naplakav.html) є такі версії

> **Перша версія** — це зоологічна версія. Коти від природи нечасто ллють
>   сльози, хоча слізні канали у кішок є. Тому й пішов вислів, що від
>   кішки сліз не дочекаєшся, тобто сліз мало.
>
> **Друга версія** каже, що вираз «кіт наплакав» походить від арабського
>   вираження «котыъ наилак», що перекладається «перестати отримувати
>   достатньо грошей». Ось і побачили схожість з сумним котом і стали
>   застосовувати відносно малої кількості грошових коштів — «грошей кіт
>   наплакав».

Особисто, я більше вірю в першу версію.

Comment: На рахунок вашого першого джерела, здається це теж один із недолугих перекладів, бо бачу такі словосполучення як: "Антонимичные вирази", "мало-мальськи" тощо.  Проте, я не зміг знайти сайту з якого б було переписано цей текст, тому я не впевнений, що це так.

Comment: @Анатолій, а я [знайшов](http://fb.ru/article/225733/kakovo-znachenie-frazeologizma-kot-naplakal) :). Але тут така річ — російське «как кот наплакал» й українське «як кіт наплакав» очевидно споріднені (якщо не походять одне від одного, то мають спільне походження), тому мені здається, інформація щодо російського «как кот наплакал» буде доречною.

Comment: @Sasha, так погоджуюся з вами, він точно набагато кращий за той переклад, який знайшов я на сайті "Як правильно зробити")

Answer (score 0):

Маю таку версію: колись колосок з зерном  був на все стебло, але розгнівали люди Бога і він вирішив покарати їх і був великий неврожай, зерен не було взагалі… люди бідкалися… от кіт і став просити хліба у Бога плачучи , Господь змилувався і вирішив, що лишить лише частинку колоса. Таким чином ми маємо колосок на частині стебла. І вислів так мало, як кіт наплакав. А коти назавжди стали домашніми тваринами за те, що випросили хліба людям..